# Robotium How to click or enter or select a file in Downloads folder on android device to open options

Tags: automated-testing, java, mobile, android

Robotium How to click or enter or select a file in `Downloads` folder on android device to open options as (`Gallery, Image Gallery, Photos, etc`)

Here is my code:

```
        String filepath = "/Downloads/";
        File file = new File(filepath +"images.jpeg" );
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   intent.setClassName("com.android.providers.downloads.ui", "com.android.providers.downloads.ui.DownloadList");
   getInstrumentation().getContext().startActivity(intent);
   setActivityIntent(intent);
        Solo solo2 = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
   solo2.getCurrentViews();
   assertNotNull(solo2);
   solo2.clickInList(1);
   solo2.sendKey(solo2.ENTER);
   solo2.waitForDialogToOpen(10000);
        solo2.clickInList(1);
        solo2.clickOnButton("Just once");
        ....
```

I try to run it and get the next error:

```
"junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: AbsListView is not found!
at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Waiter.waitForAndGetView(Waiter.java:501)
at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Clicker.clickInList(Clicker.java:450)
at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Clicker.clickInList(Clicker.java:430)
at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo.clickInList(Solo.java:1170)
at com.nsi.mobile.client.autotest.TestPrintQueue.testPrintfromOutside(TestPrintQueue.java:104)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:192)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:190)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:175)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1584)"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is because the Robotium solo could just use the classes, that **you own**.
Maybe [this](http://hitherejoe.com/testing-the-android-camera-and-gallery-picker-with-robotium/) solution could help for you.

Answer (score 1):

With Robotium, you only have access to activities that belong to your application. Gallery, Image Gallery, Photos, ect. launch activities that do not belong to your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write tests with pre-installed apps use UIAutomator testing framework from Google: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/index.html

Comment: That might be good information for someone who is just looking into doing the test, but are you sure this actually helps user solve the problem they're facing? Does UIAutomator integrate with Robotium?

Comment: You may easy add uiautomator framework library to test project. So I believe you may use Robotium and UIAutomator together

Answer (score 0):

I've just had this exact problem too.

I'm running the tests on my phone (Nexus 4, 4.4.2) and I realised I got the `'junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: AbsListView is not found!'` exception when my phone screen was *on but locked*. Yes, really.

Unlock phone => bam, test passes again.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question